# Change select UiPickerView text based on a string

Tags: swift, uipickerview

Hi I have a `UIPickerView` with strings inside, what I want is to select the text based on a string: I try to explain myself with a pseudo-language, what I would like to get is something like this:

```
if uipicker.gettext ()! = "mystring" {
    uipicker.selectext("mystring)
}
```

How can i do to get this in swift?

Comment: Selection: Your `UIPicker` is populated with an Array, no? It only provides `selectRow(_:inComponent:animated:)`, so you need to find the index of `"myString"` that correspond to that row and then use that method. Get selected string: Use `selectedRow(inComponent:)`. Same here, use the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely have an `Array` of strings to populate your picker, let say you have:

```
let data = ["string 1", "string 2", "string 3"]
```

You implement your `UIPickerView` something like this:

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return data[row]
}
```

Then you can create a method that for a given `String` selects row in the picker

```
func selectPicker(withText text: String) {
    if let index = data.index(of: text) {
        picker.selectRow(index, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    } else {
        print("text not found")
    }
}
```

And you are done :)

Comment: index(of: text) is now firstIndex(of: text) as of Swift 5